# Return if more than x day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a list of transactions per day and per customer. I need to find the customers/transaction date that had more than x occurrences of transactions on Sundays over a 6 month period.

Note, there might be more than 1 transaction per customer per day but as long as they have even 1 transaction on a Sunday then that Sunday counts towards the Sunday count for the 6 month period.

This is the code I have so far. I used the sum(transactionvalue) as a method of combining possible multiple transactions on a day into 1 record:

```
select customernumber,sum(transactionvalue),date from transactions  
where date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-06-01'
and datename(weekday, date) = 'Sunday'
group by customernumber,date
having count(date) >= x
```

However, as I change the count value i.e. 'x' gets bigger, the records for a given customer gets smaller. If a customer has 7 Sundays over the time period then I expect to return 7 records whether x is 1 or 7. Only when x is greater than 7 should all of that customer's transactions not be returned.

Here is some sample data:

```
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+
| Customer Number | Date       | Transaction Amount |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+
| 1               | 17/05/2015 | 11.00              |
| 2               | 17/05/2015 | 21.00              |
| 2               | 17/05/2015 | 22.00              |
| 3               | 17/05/2015 | 31.00              |
| 3               | 17/05/2015 | 32.00              |
| 3               | 17/05/2015 | 33.00              |
| 1               | 24/05/2015 | 11.00              |
| 2               | 24/05/2015 | 21.00              |
| 3               | 24/05/2015 | 31.00              |
| 2               | 31/05/2015 | 21.00              |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+
```

In this example I'm looking to have the following returned if x = 1:

```
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+
| Customer Number | Date       | Transaction Amount |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+
| 1               | 17/05/2015 | 11.00              |
| 2               | 17/05/2015 | 43.00              |
| 3               | 17/05/2015 | 96.00              |
| 1               | 24/05/2015 | 11.00              |
| 2               | 24/05/2015 | 21.00              |
| 3               | 24/05/2015 | 31.00              |
| 2               | 31/05/2015 | 21.00              |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+
```

But this returned if x = 3:

```
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+
| Customer Number | Date       | Transaction Amount |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+
| 2               | 17/05/2015 | 43.00              |
| 2               | 24/05/2015 | 21.00              |
| 2               | 31/05/2015 | 21.00              |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "If a customer has 7 Sundays over the time period then I expect to return 7 records whether x is 1 or 7. "? Can you show us some rows you expect?

Comment: I mean if the customer has had transactions on a given Sunday (regardless of how many on that Sunday) that counts as 1 Sunday. If they have 7 or more of such Sundays then I want to have that returned. As x increases I expect to see the records reduce as maybe only a few customers had transactions on more than 7 any given Sunday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select customernumber, date, sum(transactionvalue) as transaction_amt
from transactions   
where date >= '2015-01-01' and date < '2015-07-01'
    and datename(weekday, date) = 'Sunday'
and customernumber in (
  select customernumber
  from transactions  
  where date >= '2015-01-01' and date < '2015-07-01'
      and datename(weekday, date) = 'Sunday'
  group by customernumber
  having count(distinct date) >= 3
)    
group by customernumber, date
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e90d7/7)**